# DataFrame to_csv in pandas introduces the character " in certain columns. How to avoid that?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a dataframe, after using `to_csv` in `pandas` the output csv file has unwanted `"` on certain columns. How to avoid that?

Comment: could you show an example? I assume you have to strip of the " before you write to_csv

Comment: but none of the columns in the dataframe has " it is introduced on the columns which have names in japanese character. see the example below

Comment: 0,6538,"  キャリアインデックス
",0621.87,"  ピムコ世界金融ハイブリッド証券戦略Ｆ（毎月・通貨プレミアム）
",29281,"  ＲＩＺＡＰグループ
",5218,"  オハラ
",TSLA,"  テスラ
"

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this using [csv.QUOTE_NONE](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_NONE):

```
import csv
df.to_csv('my_file.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```